# Reading 200K rows excel and doing a DB operation using the data with nodejs

Tags: node.js, oracle, exceljs

I am new to NodeJs. I have to read 200K rows Excel .xslx file and using that data need to call DB and based on the query result needs to do some logic. I have implemented reading and writing on excel using exceljs module. But When I call DB I want to read 500 rows of chunk and form query call the DB as I dont want call DB for each row. My question is it possible to read chunk of data first 500 row from Excel then do some DB operation once its done read next chunk etc. Or is there any other package available to do this.

Comment: Which db are you using with your node app ? On top of that, which ORM/ODM ?

Comment: @KristofDcu Its Oracle DB. Its ORM.

Comment: You said "it's ORM", but which ORM do you use ? TypeORM ?

Comment: @KristofDcu I am not sure about the TypeORM. But I am planning to use SQL select query like Native SQL in NodeJS. As I am not sure is there option available like JPA in case of Java to interact with DB. Main reason I want to limit no of rows is to reduce number of DB calls.

Comment: From googling, exceljs has a streaming mode, so it seems feasible.  Without knowing the number of records or what the 'DB operation' is, I can't comment on whether you actually want to do this.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I need to process total of 200K records and I will execute select query on DB. Looking for execute a query for every 500-700 chunks of data. Means read 700 records from excel file take a specific column data and form a select query with 700 reords and check those data available in DB if there take those rows and perform some logic then take next 700  records from excel and so on or if possible do the same process in parallely.

Comment: Explore solutions like loading all the data into some temporary table and then running the queries from a stored PL/SQL procedure.  You might find this faster than many back-and-forth round-trips.  Check for solutions for loading excel to Oracle DB.  And/or use `executeMany()`.